# I am having problems saving several files totaling over 4gb on FAT32 drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, storage, format, fat32, imovie

So after reading about FAT32, I understood that you can't download a file greater than 4gb on FAT32. I am fine with that.  But here is the problem I am having. I have a 1.9tb thumb drive that I am trying to use on my firestick using an OTG USB cable. It is only compatible with FAT32. I downloaded movies on the drive so I can view later.  Each movie is less than 2gb each.  I figured that I would be able to fill this thumb drive up.  Unfortunately as soon as my total storage gets over 4gb, something happens to my thumb drive and it becomes unrecognizable and I have to reformat it and start all over.  It has happened to me three times.  It appears that even if each of the files are less than 4gb, the drive is still limited to a total storage of 4gb. Is this correct?

Comment: If you paid much less than $£€ 1000 for it, it's most probably a fake. Have you tested it? This is a real one - see the price - https://www.uk.insight.com/en-gb/productinfo/id/0006989063-00000001?alert=categoryresults

Comment: The phrase `only compatible with FAT32` sets off alarm bells. There is no technical reason for a genuine block device to be incompatible with any filesystem. The reason in this case is the fact FAT32 creates structures only near the beginning. Additionally at least some implementations (drivers) tend to allocate space from the beginning of the data area. So after a quick formatting all seems to work for a while. Filesystems that create structures somewhere in the middle or at the end, or allocate space "randomly" would fail very quickly. Restricting to FAT lets the illusion last little longer.

Comment: The Amazon Firestick is only compatible with FAT32 when using OTG USB Cable

Comment: The Amazon Firestick is only compatible with FAT32 when using OTG USB Cable. Not sure what that price is that you listed. I am from the U.S. I paid $19.99 for it. I know that is extremely cheap but it isn't fake. After further tests, I was able to put over 6gig on it with no issues. I conducted this test on my pc. Previously I was transferring video to the SD card via my firestick using an APP called ES File Explorer File Manager. I decided to run another test. I only put 2gb on the drive and left it plugged into the firestick. Within minutes it lost its formatting.

Comment: So you think that reputable companies are selling this product for $1000 while you can get a legitimate no-name alternative for $20?

Answer (score 3):

It's a fake 2 TB drive. It actually has only 4 GB (or maybe 8 GB) of memory chips inside. Once you exceed some threshold your data starts overwriting filesystem structures because it "wraps around" memory chips.

You can "salvage" this drive by creating a 4 GB partition at the very beginning.

Comment: it isn't fake. I conducted another test.

Comment: There's absolutely no way you can get a 2 TB flash drive for $20 in 2020. This price is screaming fake.